# If vloopup Return Values Query

Tags: excel, if-statement, match, vlookup

Ok this is a tad complicated to explain and im guessing even harder to solve.  Im trying to automate a debtor's list at my work so we don't have to manually change it every week which can take hours.  Currently we have one master file that contains all amounts owed to us and another that lists all outstanding amounts and any information on that client relevant to the invoice.

The master file is automated from a CSV file however i am attempting to integrate the overdue list into this and make it automated as possible.  This issue im having is if i automate the debtors list then any comments i have are also erased

Client-----Invoice #-----Amount-----Comment

X----------1-------------400--------Will not pay until (###)

Y----------2-------------500--------Having an issue with designs

Z----------3-------------600--------Something

What happens when i automate this is that the comments remain however all the other columns are replaced with the current data which messes the entries up.  Essentially what i thought to do is the following however im not sure how to implement it.

- Have the master debtor list on one worksheet and another sheet for the debtor's and comments
- Using a formula the 2nd sheet will extract values from the master sheet based on the following:

  - If the invoice number is on the master list and not the 2nd sheet then all information will be copied to the 2nd sheet.
  - If the invoice number is on the master list and the 2nd sheet nothing will be done
  - If the invoice number is on the 2nd sheet but not on the master list the information will be deleted

I basically want the information to be retrieved if it isn't there, deleted if it isn't on the master list and left alone if it is on both already.  This will therefore let people add comments but automatically delete once payment has been recorded.

Any help would be fantastic as ive tried a huge amount of If, vlookup, match etc and can't seem to get the result id like.

Comment: Formulas do not delete rows on ' the master list' and and attempt to recursively match the two worksheets without VBA will likely result in circular references. It's a interesting project and you've written a decent software specification but it still a software specification and [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) is not a free code writing service. Get started with the macro recorder and come back and edit your question to include your own effort when you run into trouble reforming the recorded code for the larger purpose.

Comment: Fair enough and thanks for the reply.  Other than the delete part is there anyway to at least copy things from the master list to the 2nd sheet.  So far the best i have come up with is an IF statement that then uses vlookup to copy a value however i keep getting double ups and not sure how to stop this.  Im sure theres a way to do this at least on excel rather than implementing a macro.

Comment: You cannot provide an automatic formula-based link between the two because you overwrite the master sheets with new CSV information every week. This breaks any relationship between the two worksheets and leaves the comments typed in manually essentially orphaned. If I was doing this, I would automate the import of the CSV to keep it in a controlled environment and add a post=processing routine that updated the information on the second worksheet according to the newly refreshed CSV information.

Comment: That makes sense.  Is it possible to perhaps have one 3 sheets to do this?  On one sheet could it compare the other two (master and debtor) and return the values that are not on both.  Then i could manually just bulk copy the entries on a new sheet to the debtors every week or whatever.  Sorry i know im being annoying just trying to make this as simple as i can with as little manual input possible. Thanks for the help so far